# For-loop macro in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

This macro to implement a C-like for-loop in Lisp is mentioned on this page: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124930/how-useful-are-lisp-macros

```
(defmacro for-loop [[sym init check change :as params] & steps]
  `(loop [~sym ~init value# nil]
     (if ~check
       (let [new-value# (do ~@steps)]
         (recur ~change new-value#))
       value#)))
```

So than one can use following in code:

```
(for-loop [i 0 , (< i 10) , (inc i)] 
   (println i))
```

How can I convert this macro to be used in Racket language?

I am trying following code:

```
(define-syntax (for-loop) (syntax-rules (parameterize ((sym) (init) (check) (change)) & steps)
  `(loop [~sym ~init value# nil]
     (if ~check
       (let [new-value# (do ~@steps)]
         (recur ~change new-value#))
       value#))))
```

But it give "bad syntax" error.

Comment: So, `syntax-rules` is different from `defmacro` in pretty significant ways, and Scheme/Racket is pretty different from Clojure. If you want, you could implement a similar concept in Racket using macros as well, but it would look a little different—Clojure and Racket are related languages, but they are not the same, and they are certainly not source compatible. However, Racket already comes with some very nice for loops, which are just plain old macros, themselves. [Take a look at the docs for more info!](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html)

Comment: There are so many useful ones but not the classical one. How can we write a macro for this in Racket.

Comment: I have noted in my answer how to implement this in Racket, but it’s also worth noting that the [Racket `do` loop](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._do%29%29) is almost identical to the `for-loop` macro you have mentioned in your question. However, I’ve elaborated in my answer why this construct is almost never used.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The snippet of code you have included in your question is written in Clojure, which is one of the many *dialects* of Lisp. Racket, on the other hand, is descended from Scheme, which is quite a different language from Clojure! Both have macros, yes, but the syntax is going to be a bit different between the two languages.

The Racket macro system is quite powerful, but `syntax-rules` is actually a slightly simpler way to define macros. Fortunately, for this macro, `syntax-rules` will suffice. A more or less direct translation of the Clojure macro to Racket would look like this:

```
(define-syntax-rule (for-loop [sym init check change] steps ...)
  (let loop ([sym init]
             [value #f])
    (if check
        (let ([new-value (let () steps ...)])
          (loop change new-value))
        value)))
```

It could subsequently be invoked like this:

```
(for-loop [i 0 (< i 10) (add1 i)]
  (println i))
```

There are a number of changes from the Clojure code:

1. The Clojure example uses `` ` `` and `~` (pronounced “quasiquote” and “unquote” respectively) to “interpolate” values into the template. The `syntax-rules` form performs this substitution automatically, so there is no need to explicitly perform quotation.
2. The Clojure example uses names that end in a hash (`value#` and `new-value#`) to prevent name conflicts, but Racket’s macro system is *hygienic*, so that sort of escaping is entirely unnecessary—identifiers bound within macros automatically live in their own scope by default.
3. The Clojure code uses `loop` and `recur`, but Racket supports tail recursion, so the translation just uses [“named `let`”](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/let.html#%28part._.Named_let%29), which is really just some extremely simple sugar for an immediately invoked lambda that calls itself.
4. There are a few other minor syntactic differences, such as using `let` instead of `do`, using ellipses instead of `& steps` to mark multiple occurrences, the syntax of `let`, and the use of `#f` instead of `nil` to represent the absence of a value.
5. Finally, commas are not used in the actual use of the `for-loop` macro because `,` means something different in Racket. In Clojure, it is treated as whitespace, so it’s totally optional there, too, but in Racket, it would be a syntax error.

A full macro tutorial is well outside the scope of a single Stack Overflow post, though, so if you’re interested in learning more, take a look at [the Macros section of the Racket guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html).

It’s also worth noting that an ordinary programmer would not need to implement this sort of macro themselves, given that [Racket already provides a set of very robust `for` loops and comprehensions built into the language](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html). In truth, though, they are just defined as macros themselves—there is no special magic just because they are builtins.

Racket’s `for` loops do not look like traditional C-style `for` loops, however, because C-style `for` loops are extremely imperative. On the other hand, Scheme, and therefore Racket, tends to favor a *functional* style, which avoids mutation and often looks more declarative. Therefore, Racket’s loops attempt to describe higher-level iteration patterns, such as looping through a range of numbers or iterating through a list, rather than low-level semantics like describing how a value should be updated. Of course, if you *really* want something like that, [Racket provides the `do` loop](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmore-scheme..rkt%29._do%29%29), which is almost identical to the `for-loop` macro defined above, albeit with some minor differences.

Comment: I've always translated `do` as `begin`. Why prefer `let`? Curious.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Because `let` permits internal definitions, whereas `begin` does not. Sometimes `begin` is preferable because of how it is spliced into the surrounding context (it does not introduce a new scope), but in cases like this, there is no context to splice into, so `let` is always the preferable choice.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation! Allowing internal definitions definitely makes it more user-friendly.

Answer (score 5):

I want to expand on Alexis's excellent answer a bit. Here's an example usage that demonstrates what she means by `do` being almost identical to your `for-loop`:

```
(do ([i 0 (add1 i)])
    ((>= i 10) i)
  (println i))
```

This `do` expression actually expands to the following code:

```
(let loop ([i 0])
  (if (>= i 10)
      i
      (let ()
        (println i)
        (loop (add1 i)))))
```

The above version uses a named `let`, which is considered the conventional way to write loops in Scheme.

Racket also provides `for` comprehensions, also mentioned in Alexis's answer, which are also considered conventional, and here's how it'd look like:

```
(for ([i (in-range 10)])
  (println i))
```

(except that this doesn't actually return the final value of `i`).

Answer (score 3):

I want to rewrite on Alexis's excellent answer and Chris Jester-Young's excellent answer for people not familiar with `let`.

```
#lang racket
(define-syntax-rule (for-loop [var init check change] expr ...)
  (local [(define (loop var value)
            (if check
                (loop change (begin expr ...))
                value))]
    (loop init #f)))

(for-loop [i 0 (< i 10) (add1 i)]
          (println i))
```